# Wikiwand keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, google-chrome-extensions

I have been using [Wikiwand](https://www.wikiwand.com/) (Chrome extension) since 2017 and I seem to remember it having keyboard shortcuts, like `/` to bring up a search box.

With the recent styling update the keyboard shortcuts seem to have gone, or am I imagining it?